# Access Apache Solr from Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, solr, server, wamp

I have created a server using the Wampp, so I don't upload files on FTP. I'm using my computer as a server and I'm sharing Wordpress website to the web from my PC
(Windows server). That part works pretty good. My concern is how I can make Apache Solr which works on Localhost accessible out of my server/PS.

When I open the website from my PC where the Wordpress site and Apache Solr is started I can create a GET request to localhost. But when I use some other device to visit the website and create some GET request to Apache Solr I get the error for URL because Localhost url doesn't work from that device.

How I can create Apache Solr core accessible from other devices on the web so I can use the URL to create a GET requests?

Comment: You should not expose Solr directly to the web - there is no inherent security present by default. Anyone would be able to remove or add documents, cores and collections. What _problem_ are you trying to solve by having Solr open to the world?

Comment: To try to be more clear and direct - How I can search in Apache Solr core from website which is online on the web? I have my core created with all the data in it and I'm running it on localhost.
Apache solr core with data and Wordpress website are on the same PC. I'm using my PC as a server for website.

Comment: If you're going to search from Wordpress (i.e. use one of the Solr-plugins for Wordpress), using localhost as a host works perfectly fine if Solr and Wordpress run on the same computer. The search will go through your Wordpress installation - Solr will not talk directly to your user's client.

Comment: Works perfectly when I'm testing it from the PC where server is setup. But when I use another device, doesn't work. I tried to create the GET request with JS, without any WPplugin.
I added input and btn in php file and when I press on btn I'm running HTTP request using Js to the Solr (http://prntscr.com/k270jr) this is the resp when I'm searing on the site from the PC with server. And when I search from another PC (http://prntscr.com/k271ax). BTW I have a problem wit CORS with JS but I'm using Chrome addon for testing without problem, but that need to be fixed too.

Comment: As I said, you really shouldn't expose Solr directly to the web without knowing what you do - the requests should be proxyed through a controller (PHP/Node/etc.)  and then to Solr, instead of going directly from the user's browser. Solr is not designed for being exposed to the internet.